# Why use binary shifts in enums

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums

I'm looking at this code:

```
/**
 * Bitmask of states
 */
export const enum ViewState {
    FirstCheck = 1 << 0,      // result is 1
    ChecksEnabled = 1 << 1,   // result is 2
    Errored = 1 << 2,         // result is 4
    Destroyed = 1 << 3        // result is 8
}
```

I don't understand why not simply specify the integer results there or integer numbers `0,1,2,3`. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Because it's easier to read (it is for me anyways and apparently the author as well). As this list grows its much easier (for a human) to add a 16th element and use `1<<15` then figure out what the resulting value would be. So just a matter of preference.

Comment: @Igor, thanks for you suggestion, but in code it's still always `ViewState.Destroyed`, so it doesn't really matter what number is there

Comment: If the intent is for multiple values to be ORed together (which is typical for a bitmask), then it **does** matter what numbers are there.

Comment: What do you mean its always `it's still always ViewState.Destroyed`? There are 4 values, maybe there will be a 5th one later. The author could have this as the convention for writing enum flags even if there are only 4 items.

Comment: @Igor, ah, yeah, thanks, I didn't understand what you meant at first

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, right, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's easier to read (it is for me anyways and apparently the author as well). As this list grows its much easier (for a human) to add a 16th element and use 1<<15 then figure out what the resulting value would be. So just a matter of preference

The reason for using shifts is that you can combine multiple states into a single value. Example: A value of 6 would be `Errored` and `ChecksEnabled`.

```
var combined = ViewState.ChecksEnabled | ViewState.Errored;

var isChecksEnabled = (combined & ViewState.ChecksEnabled) == ViewState.ChecksEnabled;
// or
var isChecksEnabled = !!(combined & ViewState.ChecksEnabled);
```

Comment: @Maximus - there is a quick example of how to combine and an example on how to check if there is a value. Maybe that is what you were looking for?

Comment: yeah, got it, thanks a lot for your explanation. All those values in ViewState will have only one bit set, that's why I get 1,2,4,8..16,32... and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This enum models the idea of four flags, each of which can be either on/true/one or off/false/zero. You can set the enum to a value by logically OR-ing together the values you want. For example:

```
z = ViewState.FirstCheck | ViewState.ChecksEnabled
```

Later in the code you can check these values independently of each other by logicall AND-ing the value with the one you want to check:

```
if (z & ViewState.FirstCheck) {
  do_something();
}

if (z & ViewState.ChecksEnabled) {
  do_something_else();
}
```

The simplest way to ensure you can decompose the enum value into a distinct, unambiguous set of flags is to have the separate values as powers of two.